# pass imageURI to another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, redirect

I use PhoneGap to create mobile app which can select image from album, and then I want to pass that image and show in another html page. Anybody have any idea how to do that? Here is my code

selectImage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var pictureSource;
        var destinationType;

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady(){
            pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
            destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        }

        function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI){

            window.location.href = "review.html";

            var image = document.getElementById('image');
            image.style.display = 'block';
            image.src = imageURI;
        }

        function getPhoto(source){
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,
                destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: source});
        }

        function onFail(msg){
            alert('Failed because: ' + msg);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button>
    <!--<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="image" src="" />-->

</body>
</html>
```

review.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Review</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>

        <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="image" src="" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html5 localstorage.

```
localStorage.seItem('url','your image path');
```

On the next page access it in

```
var myUrl = localStorage.url
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Cordova runs on a WebView you should be able to send it through the URL as a parameter and then fetch it on the next page.

**Redirect and attach photoId as URL parameter**

```
window.location.href= "review.html?photoId=1354123";
```

**Grab it on the other side using JS**

```
//Generic function to fetch URL query strings
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var photoId = getParameterByName('photoId'); //grab it
```